# Maximum value of tanh Z

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

$$ f(z) = \tanh (z) =  \dfrac{e^z - e^{-z}}{e^z + e^{-z}} $$

Find the point $z$ with $|z| \leq1$  where $|f(z)|$ attain its maximum.

I figured out that the maximum is probably at the edge (concluded it from cauchy integral formula ) but I am not sure what is my next step
(In section a,b of the question I found the taylor expansion around $z=0$ and the radius of convergence)

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|z|=1,$ you can write $\tanh(z)=\frac {e^{e^{i\theta}}-e^{e^{-i\theta}}}{e^{e^{i\theta}}+e^{e^{-i\theta}}}$, then in theory can take absolute value and the derivative with respect to $\theta$.  [This Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28+%28tanh%28exp%28i+x%29%29%29%29) indicates the maxima are at $z=\pm i$, with $|\tanh z| = \tan 1 \approx 1.5574$

Comment: Thanks but what is the maximum of $$ |tan x| $$? Isnt it undefined ?

Comment: I lost a layer of exp there.  It should be $x=\exp(i \theta)$  Working.  It looks from [this Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28+%28tanh%28exp%28i+x%29%29%29%29) to be at $\theta=\pm \frac \pi 2$

Comment: Still dont get it. 
The graph of $$ | tanh (z) | $$ is different from the graph you attached.
[link] www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs(+(tanh(z)))

Comment: Yes, I plotted $|\tanh (\exp(ix))|$, where $x$ is the $\theta$ above.  This forces it to the unit circle.

Comment: great, thanks a lot.